# ¿Como crear un limit/offset en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

No uso `sqlserver` y por tal motivo me he puesto en la tarea a consultar como crear un `limit`, me he dado cuenta que para traer cierta cantidad de registros de una consulta uso `SELECT TOP cantidad`, ejecute la consulta y efectivamente me trajo la cantidad de registros...

El problema que tengo es como decirle a la consulta que me traiga desde unvalor inicial a otro, es decir, desde el 1000 hasta el 2000.

**SENTENCIA**

```
    SELECT TOP ".$rowperpage."
      maepro.PRCODI,
      maepro.PrNomb
    FROM
      maepro
    WHERE
      maepro.PrSta = 'S' ".$searchQuery." ORDER BY maepro.PrNomb ASC";
```

Agradeceria el interes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza las cláusulas `offset` y `fetch`, que son parte de la cláusula [`order by`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions) a partir de SQL Server 2008.

Su uso es así:

- Con `offset` indicas el corrimiento de filas en el que inicia tu página actual.
- Con `fetcn next X rows only` indicas el tamaño de la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que va a lucir así en una consulta:

```
select campo1, campo2
  from MiTabla
 order by campo2
offset 10 rows 
 fetch next 10 rows only;
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba añadiendo a tu consulta lo siguiente justo después del ORDER BY

```
OFFSET 999 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Offset es la Keyword para indicar cuántos registros saltarse y con el uso de Fetch la indicamos cuántos registros tomar

[Aquí la fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#Offset) que consulte

Answer (score 1):

Lo recomendado es que al momento de ejecutar la clausula `Order By`, tomes campos que sean distintos. Es decir primero ejecutas:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla
ORDER BY campo1;...(1)
```

Luego:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
ORDER BY campo1
OFFSET 2 ROWS  --Indica la posicion del registro Inicial...(el resultado de ..(1))
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY; --Indica la posicion del resultado registro Final que quieres tomar..(el resultado de..(2)).
```

Comment: Hola Dario, bienvenido a StackOverflow. He editado tu respuesta para darle formato al código. Te invito a dar clic en [edit] para ver cómo funciona. Un saludo.