# Select rango de filas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta en SQL Server la cual me da el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es tener dos consultas, una que me muestre los 9 primeros registros del resultado anterior, y otra consulta que me muestre a partir de la fila 9 en adelante.
Algo así como LIMIT 9,8 por ejemplo, solo que LIMIT no existe en SQL Server.

Mi query es así:

```html
SELECT * FROM (SELECT P.Cod_Prod, P.Campo, P.Temp, P.Semana, SUM(P.Entregado) AS Entregado 
from(
select Codigo, Campo, Temp, Semana, sum(Convertidas) as Entregado 
FROM MyTabla where Estatus <> 'C' group by Codigo, Campo, Temp, Semana 
)P where P.Codigo='01896' and P.Campo=1 AND P.Temp=1819 group by P.Codigo, P.Campo, P.Temp, P.Semana
)P group by P.Codigo, P.Campo, P.Temp, P.Semana, P.Entregado
```

Comment: Revisa si alguna de las respuestas dadas a esta pregunta te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270982/como-crear-un-limit-offset-en-sql-server/270987#270987

Answer (score 0):

El limit no existe en SQL Server, sin embargo puedes usar el TOP que hace prácticamente lo mismo.

Ejemplo:

```
Select top 8 * 
from table_name;
```

Ahora seria cuestión que estructuraras la consulta para que primero te muestre los primeros 9 y la otra consulta donde te quite los 9 que ya mostraste anteriormente.

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta, pero esa es mi duda, como hacer otra consulta donde quite los 9 que ya mostré anteriormente...?

Comment: Ah! Desconozco la estructura de tu tabla, pero he de suponer que tienes una llave primaria o algun identificador unico, entonces puedes decirle a la tabla que seleccione todos excpeto los que esten dentro de una subconsulta, es decir
Select * from table_name where id not in (select top 8 id from table_name)

Comment: Así es, tengo un ID único, pero como puedo hacer esa subconsulta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones, una de ellas es esta:

```sql
SELECT TOP (9) * FROM [TuTabla]
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM [TuTabla]
ORDER BY [AlgunCampo]
OFFSET 9 ROWS
```

Estas dos consultas devolverán respectivamente a) Los primeros 9 registros, y b) Todos los registros desde el número 10 hasta el final.

También puedes recuperar los primeros 9 registros con la siguiente sintaxis, más "verbosa" pero elocuente si sabes inglés:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [TuTabla]
ORDER BY [AlgunCampo]
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 9 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server** implementa el estandar **ANSI** *Fetch Next*.

Como podrás probar, con dos variables puedes manejar la página que requieres y el número de registros que quieres paginar.

```
DECLARE @Pag int=1;     -- número de pagina
Declare @TamPag int=10; --número de registros por pagina
SELECT *
       FROM (
              SELECT P.Cod_Prod
                   , P.Campo
                   , P.Temp
                   , P.Semana
                   , Sum(P.Entregado) AS Entregado
                     from (
                            select Codigo
                                 , Campo
                                 , Temp
                                 , Semana
                                 , Sum(Convertidas) as Entregado
                                   FROM MyTabla
                                   where Estatus <> 'C'
                                   group by Codigo
                                          , Campo
                                          , Temp
                                          , Semana
                          ) AS P
                     where
                          P.Codigo = '01896'
                          and P.Campo = 1
                          AND P.Temp = 1819
                     group by P.Codigo
                            , P.Campo
                            , P.Temp
                            , P.Semana
            ) AS P
ORDER BY Cod_pro
OFFSET(@pag - 1) * @tamPag ROWS
FETCH NEXT @TamPag ROWS ONLY;
```

**Nota:** Te he quitado el último group by, porque no parece ser necesario, en tú consulta original.

---

Como ejemplo. A una tabla ficticia generada en la propia consulta, si le pido la página 1 y 5 registros por página.

```
DECLARE @Pag int=1;     -- número de pagina
Declare @TamPag int=5; --número de registros por pagina
SELECT *
       FROM (
            Select * From (values
                                (1,'a')
                              , (2,'b')
                              , (3,'c')
                              , (4,'d')
                              , (5,'e')
                              , (6,'f')
                              , (7,'g')
                              , (8,'h')
                              , (9,'i')
                              , (10,'j')
                        ) T(cod_pro, val)
            ) AS P
ORDER BY Cod_pro
OFFSET(@pag - 1) * @tamPag ROWS
FETCH NEXT @TamPag ROWS ONLY;
```

[image: Res1]

Si cambio la variable `@Pag` y le pongo un `2`, obtengo la página 2.

[image: Res2]

[Paginar registros Fetch next](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/paginar-consultas-como-estandar-ansi-offset-fetch/)

Pero en TSQL no es la única forma de paginar registros.

También lo puedes hacer con el operador Top, o con row_number, y otras formas....

[Paginar registros con Top](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/paginar-consultas-como-usando-el-top-2/)

[Paginar registros con Row_number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/paginados-usando-row_number-3/)

**Nota Importante**: La/s columna/s de ordenación debería de ser siempre determinista, de manera que se identifique un registro único. Si Cod_pro es único, es suficiente, pero sino, puedes añadir más columnas a la ordenación, hasta que lo sea.