# Paginar PHP y SQL

Tags: php, sql

Hola que tal en mysql es fácil hacer paginacion pero en sql server es diferente alguna ayuda me caería bien. Abajo esta algo del código que uso.

CODIGO PHP CON SQL

```
<?php
require_once ("conexion_sql.php");
    $query =  $_REQUEST['query'];
    $tipo = $_REQUEST['query2'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Licencia where $tipo LIKE '%".$query."%'  ORDER BY licencia DESC";  
$resultado = sqlsrv_query( $con, $query);
?>
<?php 
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>  
<?php echo $row["expediente"];?>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como crear un limit/offset en sql server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270982/como-crear-un-limit-offset-en-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que con MySQL paginas utilizando LIMIT, en SQL Server se utiliza el OFFSET (se pone al final, después del ORDER BY).

Por ejemplo: `OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` en este caso indicas que coja 10 y que tenga preparados otras 10 para la siguiente.

Por tanto, tu query quedaría del siguiente modo:

```
<?php
require_once ("conexion_sql.php");
    $query =  $_REQUEST['query'];
    $tipo = $_REQUEST['query2'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Licencia where $tipo LIKE '%".$query."%' ORDER BY licencia DESC OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY";  
$resultado = sqlsrv_query( $con, $query);
?>
<?php 
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>  
<?php echo $row["expediente"];?>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 R2 no funciona amigo