# Equivalencia entre el uso de LIMIT en mysql y sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo dicha consulta mysql para establecer una paginación:

```
SELECT a.id,a.categoria_id,c.nombre as categoria_nombre, a.codigo, a.nombre, 
a.precio_venta, a.stock, a.descripcion, a.imagen, 
a.activo FROM articulo a inner join categoria c ON
a.categoria_id=c.id WHERE a.nombre LIKE "%" + @valor + "%"
ORDER BY a.id ASC LIMIT limiteInferior, limiteSuperior
```

Quisiera saber si el siguiente procedimiento almacenado para SQL Server traduce la consulta anterior:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[articulo_listar_paginacion]
@valor varchar(100),
@limiteInferior int,
@limiteSuperior int
as
SELECT a.idarticulo,a.idcategoria,
c.nombre as categoria_nombre, a.codigo, a.nombre, 
a.precio_venta, a.stock, a.descripcion, a.imagen, 
a.estado FROM articulo a inner join categoria c ON
a.idcategoria=c.idcategoria WHERE a.nombre LIKE '%' + @valor + '%'
ORDER BY a.idarticulo ASC
OFFSET @limiteInferior -1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @limiteSuperior ROWS ONLY
```

Nota: resto uno al limite inferior para poder devolverlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Me parece que tienes que restar el limite inferior al limite superior para indicar el número de filas devueltas. Pero no estoy seguro si es así como lo quieres.

Comment: Si deseo devolver las filas entre dos rangos. Lo que no se implementar un limit en sql server. Gracias.

Comment: [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/270991/21) te explica lo que necesitas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como crear un limit/offset en sql server?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270982/como-crear-un-limit-offset-en-sql-server)

Comment: Gracias los dos links me dieron respuesta!!