# ¿Puedo realizar consultas en bloques de 20 registros? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, cluster

Tengo una tabla de 50 millones de registros y necesito mostrarlos en una pagina web, pero me piden que los muestre en bloques de 20 registros. Quisiera saber si es posible generar una consulta que me traiga los registros de 20 en 20 o eso se debe hacer a nivel de programación web? Creo que puedo usar paginación pero no lo tengo claro.

Agradezco cualquier tipo de sugerencia para la eficiencia de las consultas teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de registros que tengo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `limit` y `offset`, tengo más manejo de mysql pero si no me equivoco en sql server debería ser algo como esto:

```
select campo1, campo2
  from MiTabla
  order by campo2
offset 20 rows --Indica la posicion del registro inicial
fetch next 20 rows only; --Indica la posicion del resultado registro final que quieres tomar
```

Paso a explicarte: el `offset` le dice a sql desde que fila comenzar a buscar, en este ejemplo le dice que comience luego de la fila 20 y el `fetch next rows only` te dice la cantidad de elementos que te traerá

Puedes consultar [acá también](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270982/como-crear-un-limit-offset-en-sql-server)

Comment: Ya, pero si yo quiero los siguientes 20 registros debo volver a consultar cambiando los parámetros de offset y de fetch next rows only?

Comment: Exactamente, básicamente así es como funciona un paginador

Comment: la pregunta debio ser cerrada como duplicada. el link que pasa es lo mismo qu tu respuesta